# Is it possible to make a GUI similar to paint.net in Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I'm making a physics simulator using Libgdx and Box2d, what I want is to have a main window and another two for the ui, something similar to the ui of paint.net 
[image]

which uses external windows for tools/buttons. I will mainly add buttons on the other windows. Can I make something similar with Scene2d?

thanks in advance

Comment: can you specify the question once again?, are you looking for different screen?

Comment: no I just want to use multiple window

Comment: Look at [Scene2D](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) especially [Scene2D.ui](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui). Scene2D is libgdx 2D scene graph and Scene2D.ui is it's UI component. It should contain everything you need to create such UIs.
If you are looking for something more complex, you might take a look at TWL.
**EDIT**: It seems like Libgdx does not support TWL anymore. However scene2d itself is really powerfull, for example [Spine](http://esotericsoftware.com) is build using it.

Comment: Look at this https://github.com/kotcrab/vis-editor/wiki/VisUI. It is possible to build such UI's but I would say that it will be a difficult job. I would have gone with Swing personally.

Comment: Yes, of course you can make anything. You'll have to be more specific about what you actually don't understand.

Comment: As @Sneh mentioned Swing would be a nice options to create something like this. Check out LwjglAWTCanvas there is a test class in libgdx repository: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/lwjgl/SwingLwjglTest.java